# To get all pods in name spaces and in turn get image version of each pod using rest API's/client libraries

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cluster, kubernetes-namespace

I have https://containers.cloud.ibm.com/global/swagger-global-api - Kubernetes API swagger to drill upto each clusters details till namespaces.Using IAM token to access these API’s.
Further, i want to get all the pods of that specific namespace and in turn image version of each pod.

I have tried using https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript client libraries to fetch all pods,But how will i get the pods of namespaces from my cluster of my account programatically?

This i want to achieve either by using REST API's or some client libraries.How to use these libraries?

```
var k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
    kc.loadFromDefault();
 const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

    const listFn = () => k8sApi.listPodForAllNamespaces()
    console.log(listFn);
```

I get nothing from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have is not capturing errors. Hence you are not seeing any error even if it's not working.

First setup kubeconfig following this [guide](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_cli_install#kubectl) and use below code to get all pods of a specific namespace for example `default`

```
k8sApi.listNamespacedPod('default')
    .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! But it throws error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080
}

Comment: this app is running as pod inside the cluster or its running somewhere outside the cluster?

Comment: it's outside the cluster.

Comment: You have a kubeconfig file in .kube/config and you are able to use that kubeconfig with kubectl to run command kubectl get pods -n default?

Comment: This is an external node app trying to get cluster details of ibm cloud account and in turn namespaces,pods and image version of each pod.

Comment: Yes but its need a kubeconfig file to connect to the kubernetes cluster just like kubectl does. kc.loadFromDefault method will load Kubeconfig file from default location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215858/discussion-between-new123-and-arghya-sadhu).